Consecutive time slide windows to ignore the element once they are tirggered in a previous window
I am trying to generate alert when there are 4 events occurred within a 50 second window in flink.
I have come up with the following time slide window implementation.
        eventStream 
                .keyBy(Event::getKey)
                .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(50), Time.seconds(10)))
                .trigger(CountTrigger.of(4))
                .apply(new MyFunc());

Here when I generate 4 events, it triggers MyFunc 5 times for each window, where the 4 events fall into.
I would like to avoid this and not trigger MyFunc again for the elements for which one window has already triggered.
Basically I would like to reset the windows once the trigger is met.

The window API isn't a very good fit for this use case. The CEP library for the DataStream API, or MATCH_RECOGNIZE from Flink SQL, would be easier to work with.
